# Как загрузить Datatable в Combobox

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер. подскажите, есть

```
DataTable  Get_SPR_Status_Oper = _service.GetStatusOper("1");
```

на форме есть компонента `comboBox1`

Как в данный комбобокс загрузить данные для отображения из `Get_SPR_Status_Oper`
В данной таблице 2 поля `kod_` и `text_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как-то так :

```
BindDataSourceToCb(comboBox1, Get_SPR_Status_Oper);
BindDataSourceToCb(comboBox2, Get_SPR_Status_Oper);

public void BindDataSourceToCb(ComboBox cb, DataTable dt)
{
    cb.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
    cb.DisplayMember = "text_";
    cb.ValueMember = "kod_";
    cb.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: А если мне нужно один справочник полученный от сервера раскидать одновременно на десяток COMBOBOX, как правильно это сделать ?

Comment: @jvtheghost я бы сам `DataTable` вынес бы в доступную для всех этих комбобоксов область видимости и к примеру при загрузке формы указал бы им всем эти настройки

Comment: Как это правильно сделать, я дельфист, мышление по работе другое. А гуглить как то не нахожу ничего подходящего. Загрузку хочу сделать на свойстве private void form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: вот так и сделай

Comment: Я не могу понять, мне необходимо под каждый COMBOBOX делать свой DATATABLE, или можно каким то образом их рассинхронизировать. А то в одном COMBOBOX я выбираю значение и оно меняется сразу во всех остальных.

Comment: @jvtheghost и правда есть такой нюанс небольшой, нужно биндинг контекст обнулять, я ответ подправил, добавил функцию, чтобы не повторять весь код ну и нюанс етот тоже учел.